# Why do I get different performance metrics in mlr package when I run the same model twice?

Tags: r, mlr

I get two different performance metrics when I run this code two times in a row? and I'm not sure I understand why this is happening as I'm using the same training and testing set. I'm setting the seed in the beginning as well.

```
set.seed(42)
data(BostonHousing, package = "mlbench")
regr.task = makeRegrTask(id = "bh", data = BostonHousing, target = "medv")

lrn = makeLearner("regr.ctree")

outer=makeResampleInstance(makeResampleDesc("Holdout"),task=regr.task)
r = resample(
  learner = lrn,
  task = regr.task,
  resampling = outer,
  show.info = TRUE
)
```

This is what I get running the code the first time:

```
Resampling: holdout
Measures:             mse       
[Resample] iter 1:    20.5713143


Aggregated Result: mse.test.mean=20.5713143
```

This is what I get running the code the second time:

```
Resampling: holdout
Measures:             mse       
[Resample] iter 1:    21.9437349


Aggregated Result: mse.test.mean=21.9437349
```

Comment: I replicated your codes, and I get the same results maybe 10 times. You need to call `set.seed(42)` each time you run the process. What I understand is that you run seed once and want to get same results in each trial.

Comment: if you do it for lrn=makeLearner("regr.bartMachine"), you will get different results by running the set.seed (42) before the code is executed.

Comment: Some machine learning models don't respect the random seed that was set or require it to be set in a specific way. This might be an instance of this.

Answer (score 1):

`mlr` is not doing any changes to the global seed. It works for most learners including the one shown in your example (`"regr.ctree"`).

If in some cases it does not work this is a problem of the underlying learner.
In these cases you might want to read the docs of the learner to find out how to get reproducible results.